# React router and context

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

I am using the useContext and react-routers in my project which is structured like this:

```
<AppProvider>
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </Router>
</AppProvider>
```

I want to navigate to a path from my context file but I cannot since it is outside the router. What is the best way to achieve this?

What I want (in AppProvider component in context.js):

```
let history = useHistory()

useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = projectAuth.onAuthStateChanged((authUser) => {
    if (authUser) {
      history.push("/about");
    }
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restructure your layout to wrap `AppProvider` with `Router` and then everything will work since `AppProvider` will then get the history object used by Router when you use `useHistory`

```
<Router>
  <AppProvider>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/">
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route exact path="/about">
        <About />
      </Route>
    </Switch>
  </AppProvider>
</Router>
```

Comment: Ah, bugger, got me by 20 seconds. :) Funny on a 45 minute old post.

Comment: @DrewReese At least the solution is correct  :)